# Most Recent Akka and Play Framework?

Tags: playframework, akka, playframework-2.1

When using the latest version of Akka, Play just immediately hangs up on every HTTP connection attempt.

NoSuchMethodError: akka.actor.ActorSystem.dispatcher()Lakka/dispatch/MessageDispatcher;

What is the most-recent Akka verison compatible with Play?

```
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.2-SNAPSHOT",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2.2-SNAPSHOT missing method is still present in the [2.1.4 version](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.1.4/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/ActorSystem.scala#L325) of Akka, so it may work with Play.

Comment: SNAPSHOT is not recommended. Latest Akka version is 2.2.0-RC1. However, I have seen the same problem so right now I don't think there is a Play version that is compatible with Akka 2.2.x.

Comment: I've got Akka 2.2 working with Play 2.1.3, This is the commit in the Play 2.2 branch that you need to get it working on 2.1.3: https://github.com/gideondk/Play20/commit/761d3eb5858e8f94da52cc12760875644cf8d878